# a tag Bounce user back to same page minus any get variables

Tags: php, html, redirect

After the user submits the form, the php file redirects them upon success or failure to the same page sending back a get variable.

so the url before form maybe:
www.examplewebsite.com/test/index.php

after dependent on the result of submission

1. success: www.examplewebsite.com/test/index.php?action=success
2. fail: www.examplewebsite.com/test/index.php?action=fail

on the actual page there is some conditional statements

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['action'])) { ?>
   <?php if ($_GET['action'] == "success") { ?>
       <p>Thank you for your message, we will contact you shortly.</p>

 <?php } else if ($_GET['action'] == "fail") { ?>
    <p>It seems there was an error with the form, please <a href="../" class="alink">try again</a>.             
<?php }     
} else {  ?>
//display form
```

if the user clicks the try again link. If the page isn't index.php say test.php it won't redirect properly

**Summary**

I would like for that try again button to redirect the user back to the page they were on minus the "?action=success" part so the form can be displayed.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to redirect it to the came page by hiding the url in the form and letting php get the post and redirect back to the url with the "?action= mail" part

BUT if the url hasn't got the test.php or index.php the url comes out like www.blahblah.com/test/?action=mail  <== this works but doesn't look nice so i would like to have the index.php part put in.

Maybe its all unnecessary but I have OCD.

Comment: Just link to index.php? :/

Comment: sorry, if you check the line above the Summary header, I said if the page in that directory was for example test.php and the form was in that page it wont redirect back there. If the form is being included using php then I cant individually change each link so I need a clever  trick to take the url check the page and perform the redirect.    ... I've made an edit with some changes

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="index.php" class="alink">try again</a>
```

You just need to link him to the page itself.